# How to solve the "$\min$" function coming with absolute value in an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that if 
$|x-a|<\min(k/(2|1+b|),1)$ and $|y-b|<(k/2(1+|a|))$,
then $|xy-ab|<k.$

In this question I don't know how to deal with "$\min$" part in the first inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realise that $$\min\left\{\frac{k}{2\vert 1+b\vert};1\right\}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if } \frac{k}{2\vert 1+b\vert}\geq1\\
\frac{k}{2\vert 1+b\vert}&\text{if } \frac{k}{2\vert 1+b\vert}<1\end{cases}$$
So we have that $$\vert x-a\vert<\min\left\{\frac{k}{2\vert 1+b\vert};1\right\}.$$

This means that $\vert x-a\vert $ is always smaller than $1$. If however if $\frac{k}{2\vert 1+b\vert}<1$ then we can say that $\vert x-a\vert <\frac{k}{2\vert 1+b\vert}$. That's all there is to it.